# How to pause an audio file and start a new one by a single click?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

i'm trying to play 2 audio files with 2 buttons, when the other button is pressed should stop the played audio and start a new one.
 the problem is, when the app starts only the first clicked button will work as pause and start, while the other one just pause.

Note I. Any button i click first would work, while the other won't.

Note II. I've tried seeking to <0> also to <1> both didn't solve the issue.

Note III. i've tried to format the code for dog on click listener in a different 
 way from cat on click's, bth didn't solve the issue.

on the other hand, my app will contain something like 10 buttons, with each onclick i need to pause 9 and start one, is there a way to pause them all with a smaller code?
Thanks

```
//Buttons    
  dog = Button.findViewById(R.id.dog)
  cat = Button.findViewById.(R.id.cat)
//MediaPlayers   
  final dogMP = MediaPlayer.Create(this, R.raw.park)
  final catMP = MediaPlayer.Create(this, R.raw.meaw)
//onClicks
 //dog
  dog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            catMP.pause();
            catMP.seekTo(0);
            if (!dogMP.isPlaying()) {
                dogMP.setLooping(true);
                dogMP.start();

            } else {
                dogMP.pause();
                dogMP.seekTo(0);
            }

        }
    });
//cat
    cat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!catMP.isPlaying()) {
                dogMP.pause();
                dogMP.seekTo(0);
                catMP.setLooping(true);
                catMP.start();



            } else {
                catMP.pause();
                catMP.seekTo(0);
            }
        }
    });`
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this for all your buttons by checking `mediaplayer` try code given below.

```
//dog
   dog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               if (mediaplayer != null){
            if (mediaplayer.isplaying()) {
                mediaplayer.stop();
                // start your new audio
                    dogMP.setLooping(true);
                    dogMP.start();
            } else {
                // start your new audio
                    dogMP.setLooping(true);
                    dogMP.start();
            }
            }
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks for responding
but mediaplayer is not a declared variable, and i got an error message